# VBA rounding up to the nearest 1E-n

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

I have created a Scatter Chart using VBA in excel.
The Y-Axis has a logarithmic scaling, as the values in my data ranges (300 data ranges with a few hundred thousand data points in each one) vary from 1 to 1E-10.

Is there a way to scale the Y axis automatically? As the maximum value can vary from chart to chart from 1 to 1E-5.

If not is there a way to round up to the nearest 1E-n? So I can scale my graph using the code below.

`MyChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = "round up max value from my data range"`

Thanks in advance

Charlie

```
For cond = 2 To wb.Worksheets.Count
                    Set ws = wb.Sheets(cond)
                    wsn = ws.Name

                    With ws
                        'Includes "Title" cell
                        Set ttl = .Cells(.Columns(1).Find(what:="Title", after:=Cells(1, 1)).Row, 1)
                        Set ttl2 = .Cells(ttl.Row, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
                        Set rng1 = .Range(ttl, ttl2)
                        Set Data = .Cells(.Columns(1).Find(what:="*Pa)*", after:=Cells(1, 1)).Row + 2, 1)
                        Set Data2 = .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
                        Set rng2 = .Range(Data, Data2)
                        myrng = Union(rng1, rng2).Address
                    End With

                    ws.Shapes.AddChart.Name = (wsn)
                    ws.Shapes(wsn).Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
                    Set MyChart = ws.Shapes(wsn).Chart
                    MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range(myrng), PlotBy:=xlColumns

                    MyChart.ApplyLayout (1)
                    MyChart.ChartTitle.Text = Title & " " & wsn
                    MyChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Pressure "
                    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Output”

                    MyChart.Axes(xlValue).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
                    MyChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
                    MyChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = 0.000000001
                    MyChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = “needs automating”

                    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory).ScaleType = xlLogarithmic
                    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 10000
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Left = ws.Range("A1").Left
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Top = ws.Range("A1").Top

                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Height = 400
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Width = 1200

                    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMajorGridlines = True
                    MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMinorGridlines = True

                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Chart.Legend.Left = 1000
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Chart.Legend.Width = 190
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Chart.Legend.Top = 17.5
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Chart.Legend.Height = 360
                    ws.ChartObjects(wsn).Chart.PlotArea.Width = 975

                Next cond
```

Comment: please share the code you have for plotting the chart

Comment: This looks like it might help https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-automatically-adjust-chart-y-axis-min-and-max-values

Comment: Why, in your code, do you set a `.MaximumScale = 10000` if your range of values is `1 to 1E-5`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that's for the X-Axis, thanks

Comment: Of course, <hand hitting forehead>

Comment: Why not just use the built-in automatic scaling?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but what about:

```
With MyChart.Axes(xlValue) 
 .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True 
 .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True 
End With
```